# fullcalendar jQuery - Possible to retrieve description from Google Calendar events?

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have setup fullcalendar to load a number of google calendar events but was wondering if there is any way to load the *description* or other data from the event other than the title and times?

I'd like to grab the 'description' and 'where' fields froom google calendar events and display them in a tooltip in fullcalendar.

I was thinking of trying to parse the event.url results but it doesn't work due to cross-domain ajax requests. I suppose it may be possible through a proxy php script or the crossframe jquery thing, but I'm wondering if fullcalendar provides any access to this data more cleanly? (or if anyone has a better idea)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea they had this: interesting find.
If you look in the gcal.js source file, there's an block of code that looks like this:

```
events.push({
                        id: entry['gCal$uid']['value'],
                        title: entry['title']['$t'],
                        url: url,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay,
                        location: entry['gd$where'][0]['valueString'],
                        description: entry['content']['$t']
                    });
```

My expectation is that you can use the `location` and `description` fields to do what you want.

In fact, you could probably add any other fields from the entry object that you wanted: you'd need to know what options you have, but http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples/cal_sample.html makes it pretty straightforward to do. I'm curious why they didn't just add the entire entry object as a field, that way ALL the data would be accessible if/when you wanted it.

Comment: Wow, that was simple. I wonder why it's not documented on their website. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yea - i never bothered to look in the gcal.js :D haha- Thats mint! Thanks man

Comment: Sorry to slightly gravedig this. BUt I'm looking at the new V3 docs. They seem to have the same code but I'm a little confused as to how you actually use this to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

After losing my mind as to *why* it was so simple to add descriptions from a google calendar event, I finally found in fullcalendar.js where to put the fields. 
On line 3982 I changed

`"<div class='fc-event-title col'>" + htmlEscape(event.title || '') +`

to

```
 "<div class='fc-event-title col'>" + '<strong>' +
   htmlEscape(event.title || '') + '</strong><br>' +
   htmlEscape(event.description || '') +
```

and boom, description shows up with a little styling. 
Yes, it was simple and I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: This does work if you want to hack with there JS a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent version, you can add this way:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    element.description = event.description;
                },
```

So now, in eventMouseover or eventClick you can access to event.description.

I hope this can help.