# Fullcalendar jQuery - Possible to retrieve colour from google calendar?

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I know it is possible to set the colour for events based on a source such as a google calendar, but I was wondering if there is any way to retrieve the colour automatically as it is set on the google calendar itself?

Looking through the gcal.js, there doesn't seem to be anything pushed regarding the colour, but in google's json api (json-c however), there is a reference to the colour.

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#RetrievingAllCalendars

I suppose it is a matter of a feature request to Fullcalendar but I'm wondering if I am missing something already in there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The color of the calendar is not in the XML,ICAL Feed. It is only shown in the list of calendars available from a user. It lists the calendars and uses the:
**GCal namespace element reference**

> Google Calendar provides several
>   extension elements for use in a
>   metafeed (the feed that lists the
>   user's calendars). These elements are
>   in the gCal namespace, not the Google
>   Data namespace, because they're
>   specific to Calendar

So unfortunately, gcal.js does not support getting the list and you will not get the color unless you use another plugin to do so.

---

In that case it would have been as easy as this.
In the gcal.js where the push it - I think you can add something in the line of

```
color: entry['gCal$color']['value'],
```

Google Source feed contains this value: (Calendar list - not calendar)

```
<gCal:color value='#2952A3' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously answered a gcal/fullcalendar question at [fullcalendar jQuery - Possible to retrieve description from Google Calendar events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811352/fullcalendar-jquery-possible-to-retrieve-description-from-google-calendar-event/5811697#5811697). You will need to modify the source of `gcal.js`. You might want to just hang the Google Calendar object off the event (so you can access the color and everything else):

```
events.push({
                        id: entry['gCal$uid']['value'],
                        title: entry['title']['$t'],
                        url: url,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay,
                        location: entry['gd$where'][0]['valueString'],
                        description: entry['content']['$t'],
                        entry: entry
                    });
```

Comment: and where/how do you get the color? which lines does that?

Comment: Well, The color is only contained in the *allcalendars* feed (see http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ManagingSubscriptions). You'll need to fetch that and parse that to grab the color of each of the included calendars: you would then have to figure out which calendar the event comes from (using the *entry* object) and you'd have the color to use. My answer is not wrong, it just requires you do actually do the work.

Comment: gcal.js does not get the entire list! Your code is irrelevant and does not even show how to query for the color if it was there. which it is not..   you would need to use another plugin. your own for example to get the list and get the color.

Comment: You are correct: the color isn't in the default feed, so my code is (by itself) insufficient to do what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

I did that https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get#examples But in JavaScipt. It's works for me.

```js
   function getColors() {
       
         gapi
            .client
            .load('calendar', 'v3')
            .then(function () {
               request = gapi.client.calendar.colors.get({
                  'calendarId': calendarId  -> "Your CalendarID"

               });

               request.then(function (resp) {

                  if (resp.result.error) {
                     reportError('Google Calendar Colors: ' + data.error.message, data.error.errors);

                  } else if (resp) {

                     console.log('--- resp ---');
                     console.log(resp.result);  

                  }
               }, function (reason) {
                  console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);

               });
            });
      }
```