# FullCalendar: Use Location attribute of Google Calendar Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have setup FullCalendar (v3.8.0) to pull event data from Google Calendar, using qTip2 for displaying event information. This works fine.

**I am now trying to display the event's location attribute. Sadly, I cannot seem to figure out how to get FullCalendar to save the information from Google Calendar in the event**.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test">
    <meta name="author" content="Test">

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css' />

    <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js'></script>     
    <script src='lib/moment.js'></script>               
    <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            googleCalendarApiKey: '<<hidden>>',
            events: {
                googleCalendarId: '<<hidden>>'
            },
            header: {
                left:   'title',
                center: 'listWeek, agendaWeek, month',
                right:  'prev,next'
            },
            weekends: false,
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.qtip({
                    content: event.description,
                    title: event.title,
                    position: {
                        my: 'center',   //Ecke des Tooltips
                        at: 'center',   //Position auf der Seite (auch Target möchlich)
                        target: $(window)
                    },
                    show: 'click'
                });
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                if (event.url) {
                    return false;
                }                   
            }               
        });
    });
    </script>

    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

I have tried to add the location attribute to EventDef.defineStandardProps, but this apperas to have no effect.

```
EventDef.defineStandardProps({
    // not automatically assigned (`false`)
    _id: false,
    id: false,
    className: false,
    source: false,
    // automatically assigned (`true`)
    title: true,
    url: false,
    rendering: true,
    constraint: true,
    overlap: true,
    editable: true,
    startEditable: true,
    durationEditable: true,
    color: true,
    backgroundColor: true,
    borderColor: true,
    textColor: true,
    location: true
});
```

This was also discussed at ["fullcalendar jQuery - Possible to retrieve description from Google Calendar events?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811352/fullcalendar-jquery-possible-to-retrieve-description-from-google-calendar-even), but the solution provided appears to be outdated and not applicable anymore.
Every other thread about this topic has either no or no conclusive answer.

**Which steps can I take to be able to use the event location?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the eventRender callback (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) you shuld be able to access `event.location`, assuming Google has provided you with that field in the JSON you receive. You can check the content of the event by inserting the line `console.log(JSON.stringify(event));` into your eventRender code, to log the event properties available to you.

FullCalendar happily keeps custom properties on the event object, if the data source supplies them. Once you've got that data, you can insert it into the event's HTML however you please.

I don't know where in the process you were trying to add things to the event standard properties, but anyway that makes no sense - it would just pre-define an empty attribute, it doesn't cause it to be actually populated with anything.

Comment: Thank you! I have found my error... Everything was working all along, but most events did not have a location set in Google Calendar. Of course I only checked the ones without a location, and then thought that the location import did not work. Feeling rather stupid right now...

Comment: @user9211114 No need to be embarrassed, it's easily done, but always best to check the source data! Glad you figured it out